# "On a computer"?

Tags: law, invalidation, us6368268

In reference to the patent: [US 6,368,268](https://www.google.com/patents/US6368268)

Wouldn't the [*Alice* decision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_Corp._v._CLS_Bank_Int%27l) render this patent invalid and unenforceable?

Answer (score 1):

Doubtful. Based on the claims (which are what determines the metes and bounds of patent protection and are what would be scrutinized under an Alice analysis), it seems like substantially more than just an a abstract idea or simple implementation on a general computing device, which were address in Alice.  For example, check out the independent claims:

*Claim 1. A stimulation system comprising:
a display device;
a user interface connected to said display device, said user interface causing an image to be displayed on said display device and outputting a control signal; and,
a stimulation device receiving the control signal from the user interface, said stimulation device imparting stimulation to the user in response to the control signal.*

*Claim 8. A stimulation system comprising:
a hand-operable input device for generating a command signal in response to an input received from a first user;
a first user interface connected to said input device, said first user interface generating a control signal based upon the command signal;
a second user interface remotely located from said first user interface, said second user interface receiving the control signal; and,
a stimulation device receiving the control signal from said second user interface, said stimulation device imparting stimulation to a second user in response to the control signal.*

*17. A stimulation system comprising:
a first hand-operable input device for generating a first command signal in response to an input received from a first user;
a first user interface connected to said first input device, said first user interface generating a first control signal based upon the first command signal and receiving a second control signal;
a first stimulation device receiving the second control signal from said first user interface, said first stimulation device imparting stimulation to the first user in response to receiving the second control signal;
a second input device for generating a second command signal in response to an input received from a second user;
a second user interface remotely located from said first user interface, said second user interface receiving the first control signal and generating the second control signal based upon the second command signal; and,
a second stimulation device receiving the first control signal from said second user interface, said second stimulation device imparting stimulation to the second user in response to the first control signal.*